# How do i install GA4 on website with legecy analytics.js without having to add a second snippet

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, gtag.js, analytics.js

I want to install GA4 on a website that already have GA(universal analytics) installed on it using analytics.js . But i don't want to insert an additional script/snippet due to the concern of it adding to page load time.
So we just want to have one snippet that would work for both Universal analytics and GA4

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking that loading more scripts will reduce the speed is flawed. While it may look technically correct, it's too simplistic to be useful. The speed decrease will be rarely measurable from an async load of a small, non-blocking library like gtag.

The industry best practice, however, is to go with GTM or a different tag management system that will load scripts as required. That's exactly the one snippet for them all logic. Again, won't measurably delay the pageload, unless misused.

Finally, if loading a script is such a concern, then why loading analytics.js? Just have it all in the source? Maybe even rewrite the whole thing to send events using the measurement protocol? Same applies to GA4. All these libraries do is abstract the complexity of sending proper network requests to their endpoint.

Comment: I have lost count of the number of projects I have worked on where improving website speed has actually improved conversion rates on the website(from small companies to websites making millions in revenue). So reducing the number of script loading on a page does improve website speed. That is what website like https://gtmetrix.com and Googles own website speed checker ( https://developers.google.com/speed ) were created to help website owners resolve by recommending which script script to merge together rather (to reduce number of request made to server). So it's not flowed.

Comment: You're not exactly making a connection between removing the scripts and improving the speed, but you do you.

Comment: @user2274299, I don’t think he is negating the impact of scripts and their relationship to load times. He is saying that worrying about the analytics scripts is probably moot because they won’t increase the speeds by noticeable amounts. You can even test load times with one and two tags and see if it is even worth worrying about.